# Array of string is null ASP.NET Core Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a classes which are represented as below:

```
public abstract class TankModel
{
    protected static readonly char delimiter = ',';

    protected string _destinations = "";

    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public String[] Destinations
    {
        get
        {
            return _destinations.Split(delimiter);
        }
        set
        {
            _destinations = String.Join($"{delimiter}", value);
        }
[..........................]
    }
}

public class NormalTank : TankModel
{
    public double VolumeTotal { get; set; }
[.........]
}
```

My OnModelCreating method contains:

```
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<TankModel>().Property<string>("Outputs").HasField("_destinations");
            modelBuilder.Entity<TankModel>().ToTable("Tanks");
            modelBuilder.Ignore<TankModel>();
            modelBuilder.Entity<NormalTank>().HasBaseType<TankModel>();
[..................]
        }
```

When I'm displaying NormalTank rows, Destinations columns is empty.

I'm trying to display data without inheriting, then Destinations column has the right value. I suspect that `modelBuilder.Ignore<TankModel>();` causes this problem, but without this property I don't build a migration.

I'm fighting with this problem since few hours and I don't see any solutions.

How can I save Destinations in my database?

Comment: Have a look at here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/backing-field. Apparently, you're missing a few calls in the field mapping.

Comment: I would suggest using EF Core's (2.1 and later) [Value Converter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions) to do this tasks, rather than binding it to a backing field, it's cleaner and you don't need code for conversions. It also works well if you ever change to an document database, since then it can be mapped as an array (which isn't directly possible right now with EF Core 2.1 - but may be possible in 2.2 when/if the feature to map owned types to collection gets possible)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided you are using EF Core 2.1 or greater, you can leverage a custom [`ValueConverter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions).

E.g. for the following class:

```
public class Example
{
  public Example() { Values = new List<string>(); }
  public ICollection<string> Values { get; set; }
}
```

You can simply configure a converter in your `DbContext`:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Example>(b => b.Property(x => x.Values)
  .HasConversion(new StringCollectionToStringConverter()));
```

Having created a converter class as follows:

```
public class StringCollectionToStringConverter : ValueConverter<ICollection<string>, string>
{
  private static readonly Expression<Func<string, ICollection<string>>> ToListValue
    = str => str.Split('|', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

  private static readonly Expression<Func<ICollection<string>, string>> ToStringValue
    = list => string.Join('|', list);

  public StringCollectionToStringConverter(ConverterMappingHints mappingHints = null)
    : base(ToStringValue, ToListValue, mappingHints) { }

  public static ValueConverterInfo DefaultInfo
    => new ValueConverterInfo(typeof(ICollection<string>), typeof(string),
      i => new StringCollectionToStringConverter(i.MappingHints));
}
```